# Get MAC addresses for all clients in AD

Tags: powershell

I would like to extract from an Active Directory the MAC Address of every hostname/client. Actually use this command but what's necessary to add to see the MAC Address?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem,IPv4Address,MACAddress | select Name, IPv4Address, OperatingSystem
```

And from DHCP:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Scope | Get-DhcpServerv4Lease | Where { $_.AddressState -eq 'Active' } | select IPAddress,HostName,AddressState,ClientId
```

It's possible to merge both queries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adcomputer?view=win10-ps) MacAddress isn't an available property from Get-ADComputer. You would need to use some other method of resolving the Mac Address as it doesn't appear to be available in ActiveDirectory

Comment: AFAIK, [macAddress attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-macaddress) is not updated automatically. What's more, it seems to allow only a single address, which wouldn't even work for multihomed hosts. Try querying your DHCP server, or if there's an IPAM product, its config.

Comment: thanks! I update my previous message.

Comment: merge them how?

Comment: Combining cmdlet results is a very common thing. What did you search for?   [combining PowerShell cmdlet results](https://www.bing.com/search?q=combining++powershell+cmdlet+resuls&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=combining+powershell+cmdlet+resuls&sc=0-34&sk=&cvid=068902B0E9324D43A731C90C62FA0B5D)